# Dagger Hilt error injecting ActivityContext

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger-hilt

I'm injecting with `Dagger-Hilt` a class with a dependency on `@ActivityContext` in a ViewModel, this module is installed in `ActivityComponent` and scoped to activity and it's throwing me an error whenever I try to compile. For your information I have other modules with ActivityRetainedComponent and SingletonComponent injecting @ApplicationContext.

Now I'm trying to figure out what does this error mean.

```
error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] com.rober.fileshortcut_whereismyfile.utils.PermissionsUtils cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method.
  public abstract static class SingletonC implements App_GeneratedInjector,
                         ^
      com.rober.fileshortcut_whereismyfile.utils.PermissionsUtils is injected at
          com.rober.fileshortcut_whereismyfile.ui.fragments.filefragment.FileViewModel(�, permissionsUtils, �)
      com.rober.fileshortcut_whereismyfile.ui.fragments.filefragment.FileViewModel is injected at
          com.rober.fileshortcut_whereismyfile.ui.fragments.filefragment.FileViewModel_HiltModules.BindsModule.binds(vm)
      @dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelMap java.util.Map<java.lang.String,javax.inject.Provider<androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>> is requested at
          dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelFactory.ViewModelFactoriesEntryPoint.getHiltViewModelMap() [com.rober.fileshortcut_whereismyfile.App_HiltComponents.SingletonC ? com.rober.fileshortcut_whereismyfile.App_HiltComponents.ActivityRetainedC ? com.rober.fileshortcut_whereismyfile.App_HiltComponents.ViewModelC]
```

Here's the code (I don't think there's anything wrong here)

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)
object PermissionModule {

    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    @Provides
    @ActivityScoped
    fun providePermissionsHelper(
        @ActivityContext context: Context,
    ) = PermissionsUtils(context)
}
```

```
@HiltViewModel
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
class FileViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val class1: Class1,
    private val class2: Class2,
    private val class3: Class3,
    private val permissionsUtils: PermissionsUtils //Here's the one I'm injecting
)
```

My guesses: It's telling me that I can't inject in ActivityComponent because FileViewModel is injected in ActivityRetainedComponent/SingletonComponent/ViewModelComponent, because other dependencies provided to viewmodel are installed in this component?

**Question:** What is really going here? What am I missing and is there any solution for using ActivityComponent? I really need the `@ActivityContext` for that class!

**Edit:** This works when I change to `@InstallIn(ActivityRetainedComponent::class)` and the context to `@ApplicationContext context: Context`, note that it works with SingletonComponent/ViewModelComponent/ActivityRetainedComponent, which makes sense. But still I don't know how to make it work the `@ActivityComponent`

**Edit 2:** I've come to the conclusion that is not possible since you are installing in ViewModel and the **components that work with ViewModel are** `Singleton/ActivityRetained/ViewModel`, so there's no way to inject `ActivityContext` in a ViewModel since it requires the component `@ActivityComponent` and this is 1 level below of ViewModelComponent.

**Source:** https://dagger.dev/hilt/components#fn:1

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> so there's no way to inject ActivityContext in a ViewModel since it requires the component @ActivityComponent and this is 1 level below of ViewModelComponent.

You got it.

Think of Dagger/Hilt components (and scopes) in terms of lifecycle. In Android, a `ViewModel` has longer lifecycle than its containing `Activity` or `Fragment`. That's the whole point of the class, it's just the name that's unfortunate. It may help to think of those as `RetainedInstance` or `AnObjectThatSurvivesActivityConfigurationChanges`. Yeah, these aren't as catchy as `ViewModel`.

If you injected a short-lived object (the `Activity`) into a long-lived one (the `ViewModel`), the latter would keep a reference to the former. That's a memory leak - the `Activity` and everything it contains (e.g. views, bitmaps) stays in memory even though it's no longer used. A couple of those and you risk an `OutOfMemoryError`.

However, the other way around - i.e. injecting a long-lived object into a short-lived one - is safe. That's why you got it working with `Singleton`/`ActivityRetained`/`ViewModel` components.

Hilt's component hierarchy makes it harder for you to create memory leaks. And all of that happens at compile-time, which gives you faster feedback as opposed to runtime-based solutions. Much better than your users finding out by crashing!

Comment: Thank you for explaining it in much more detail! It's a really good answer :)

Comment: I also have same problem with this. I have a `Router` which is helping to navigate in app. So I tried to pass `@ActivityContext` to the router, then cast to actual `Activity` to call functions. This router is injected into `ViewModel`, so viewmodel would do some logic there, then calling router to navigate. Obviously, some cases we want to pass activity/fragment into a a specific class, and doing some logic there. But I failed to use @ActivityContext or passing activity/fragment into a class. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Instead of hard-referencing the `Activity` inside your `Router` (which you're now doing by injecting it through the constructor) you can attach/detach the activity instance dynamically based on its lifecycle. For example, attaching in `onStart`, detaching in `onStop` might be a good start for navigation purposes, but YMMV depending on your use cases or some platform/lifecycle-specific edge cases.